# Creating a script that takes inputs and then returns the probabilities of that event happening in Python

Tags: python, random-forest, predict

I have built a machine learning model and computer probabilities that a certain event may happen or not. More specifically I have built a Random Forest classification model to predict whether or not a flight will be late or not.

Now I want to build a script that would take in input such as Origin Airport , Destination, Reporting_Airline, Day of Week, etc, and then return to me the probability of whether the flight will be late or not, from the predictions that have already been computed.

I have wrote some code but it will not work, it returns an error saying 'Series is not callable'

Here is my code,

```
data4 = data3[['Origin', 'Dest', 'Reporting_Airline','late','DayOfWeek','Month']]
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data4, columns=['Reporting_Airline', 'Origin', 'Dest'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dummies.drop('late', axis=1),dummies.late,test_size=0.1)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model1 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=13)
model1.fit(X_train,y_train)
predicted = model1.predict(X_test)
model1.score(X_test, y_test)
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score 
probabilities = model1.predict_proba(X_test)
```

This part of the code works fine, the following is the bit where I want to take some inputs and then return probabilities based on that,

```
def predict_delay(origin, destination):
from datetime import datetime


    
origin = data4.Origin()
destination = data4.Dest()
    
input = [{'ORIGIN_ATL': 1 if origin =='ATL' else 0,
          'ORIGIN_JFK': 1 if origin =='JFK' else 0,
             'DEST_ATL': 1 if destination =='ATL' else 0,
             'DEST_JFK': 1 if destination =='JFK' else 0}]
return model1.predict_proba(pd.data4(input))[0][0]

predict_delay('ATL', 'JFK'),
```

Notice that I only included, two destinations and origins, 'ATL' and 'JFK', since there 360 destinations is my dataset, it would be a pain to write every single one of them.

Also is there an easy way I could call them from the dataset rather than defining them one by one? Since this is another error I get. After creating the dummy variables I now have 744 features/columns, the input features must also be of the same number, therefore would need to somehow pass the whole df...

Comment: There is an indentation issue in your second snippet. That said, what is your intent with `origin = data4.Origin()`? I suspect this is the problem (and next line).

Comment: @Travis I tried playing with it and changing a few parameters but this does not seem to work either. My intent is that origin, the input, would call all the origin values from data4.origin column.
However the input requires that feature columns must be the same number as the feature columns in the dummy dataframe, which is 744... It would work if I wrote out the 744 different columns manually...